# Visual Studio 2008 Installation Doesn't Work!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2008 from an ISO disc image on Windows Vista. When I try to install it, a screen goes up and hides so fast, and nothing happens.

I tried to run the setup as administrator, but that makes no difference.

Comment: Where did you get the disk from?

Comment: I made a disc image from my original DVD. Original DVD doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your event log, I would doubt nothing is logged.  Also you might just want to copy the files to a network drive or locally and just do the install, the DVD or other media is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mounting the ISO as a virtual CD, you could try burning it to a disk.  Just a thought.

Comment: You might try turning off UAC, restarting, and then trying to install again.  And it probably won't make a difference, but you could install the .NET framework (3.5 and 2.0, for good measure) before installing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds dumb, but have you tried rebooting?  Also, make sure the MS installer proc isn't running.  I've had some issues with that before where the proc never died but got hung in some strange state.